Git merge conflict - Wokring on a repo which has release, develop and feature branches. Pull request from dvelop to release resulting in conflict
I am trying to merge the devlop branch to release but it gives conflict.


It's not allowed to do changes directly in either release or develop, all the changes have to be there in feature and then go to develop via a pull request and then to release via develop.
Somehow, there were chnages made directly to the release via a feature branch and those changes are there in develop as well but via a different feature.
I think this particluar commit in release is causing the merge conflict when raising a pr from develop to release for the new changes.
I followed the steps mentioned in the above image, but since we cannot do the changes directly in release or develop, I did the following -

git checkout release
git pull
git checkout -b feature/resolveMergeConflict
git pull origin develop
resolved the conflicts manually
git commit
git push
raised a pr from feature to develop
raised a pr from develop to release - this is causing merge conflict


No promoting jetbrains, but you can use its any community ide for git related things:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mSfq1SoMocg&ab_channel=JetBrains
Other on is this for theory:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sqsz1-o7nXk&ab_channel=TheModernCoder

Just guessing: Did you carefully check what you commit in step 6, and did you work with git merge --continue, or really git commit (though I think merge --continue just runs commit)?

Hi @matheburg I worked with git rebase --continue

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

@Community the scenario is explained above.

"Somehow, there were chnages made directly to the release via a feature branch [1] and those changes are there in develop as well but via a different feature [2]" - a couple ideas (and no guarantee). One, dig out that first feature branch (maybe it wasn't deleted from origin after the merge? And even if it was, then the author very likely still has it on their machine). Merge it to the develop branch as well.
Another: fetch both the release and the develop, and do sth like
git checkout develop
git checkout -b feature/anotherAttemptAtSolvingMergeConflict
git rebase release/release

solve merge conflicts, push and PR that branch.

Hi @mbojko Please explain the difference between checking out from develop and rebasing release over it and vice versa.

If you can't push changes directly to release, then rebasing release locally is useless. What are you going to do with it if you can't push? Are you asking why rebasing a feature branch you can push is different to rebasing a branch you can't push?

I cannot push changes directly to release, but I can do it via a feature.
I am asking - the difference between checking out from develop and rebasing release over it and checking out from release and rebasing develop over it
